# how to access values from a array column in scala dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe coming with scala array of tuples (index, value) like the following, index has values from 1 to 4

```
id  | units_flag_tuples

id1 | [(3,2.0), (4,6.0)]

id2 | [(1,10.0), (2,2.0), (3,5.0)]
```

I would like to access the value from the array and put it into columns based on index (unit1, unit2, unit3, unit4):

```
ID | unit1| unit2 | unit3 | unit 4

id1 | null | null  | 2.0   | 6.0

id2 | 10.0 | 2.0   | 5.0   | null
```

here is the code:

```
df
.withColumn("unit1", col("units_flag_tuples").find(_._1 == '1').get._2  )
.withColumn("unit2", col("units_flag_tuples").find(_._1 == '2').get._2  )
.withColumn("unit3", col("units_flag_tuples").find(_._1 == '3').get._2  )
.withColumn("unit4", col("units_flag_tuples").find(_._1 == '4').get._2  )
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

> error: value find is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column

How to resolve this error or any better ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my different approach, that I have used the `map_from_entries` function to make a map for array and get each column by choosing the key from the map.

```
val df = Seq(("id1", Seq((3,2.0), (4,6.0))), ("id2", Seq((1,10.0), (2,2.0), (3,5.0)))).toDF("id", "units_flag_tuples")
df.show(false)

df.withColumn("map", map_from_entries(col("units_flag_tuples")))
  .withColumn("unit1", col("map.1"))
  .withColumn("unit2", col("map.2"))
  .withColumn("unit3", col("map.3"))
  .withColumn("unit4", col("map.4"))
  .drop("map", "units_flag_tuples").show
```

The result is:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|unit1|unit2|unit3|unit4|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|id1| null| null|  2.0|  6.0|
|id2| 10.0|  2.0|  5.0| null|
+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```